# Options for doing App Services health check for WebJob application

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-web-roles

I am hosting a few WebJobs app services and I like to use the Health check feature included in Apps Services.

My worker job applications do not expose any http endpoints. Therefore exposing the path /api/health explained in this article does not apply to my senario:

https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/08/24/healthcheck-on-app-service.html

We we have health check options other than exposing a HTTP endpoint?

Is there any way to have App Services does health check by checking a file in file system - like creating/deleting a file to check a file's update date?

Comment: What's the purpose of having a health check for the webjob? What type of trigger are you using?

Comment: @RyanHill-MSFT, thank you for help. I have a continuedly running webjob. I like to know if its core loop is running as expected.  I can use other mechanisms to do the same, but I a hoping the health check can help.

Comment: @RyanHill-MSFT, the idea is to have something similar to Kubernetes health check probes. https://newrelic.com/blog/how-to-relic/kubernetes-health-checks

Comment: You didn't tell what tech you are using but in .net for example it is quit easy to host an endpoint. That endpoint could read some (shared) state updated by the worker to indicate it is working properly or not.

Comment: @PeterBons, the idea is not to expose any endpoint. Kubernetes health check provides that option.

Comment: Yes, but azure web app is not kubernetes ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything out of box so it's something you'll have to implement yourself. Something like the WebJob calling some sort of webhook in your `while(true)` and if that webhook isn't called after a certain period, fire off an email or something that affect.

Another option is to utilize App Insights. Check the [Logging documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#logging-and-monitoring) but you could tie into [App Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started#enable-application-insights-logging) and feed that into Monitor and configure alerts.